# Error using Range.Fomula for SUBTOTAL

Tags: vba, excel

I have a function that opens and closes multiple data sources and performs a comparison between the two.  All of that is working as intended. Now, I'm trying to add a subtotal cell at the top of one of the columns so that other users can filter the output data.  Here's the relevant snippet of the code:

`wsOutputData.Range("E1").Fomula = "=SUBTOTAL(9,E3:E" & lngOutputLastRow & ")"`

When the procedure gets to this line, I get the following error:

> Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method

I've double and triple-checked that all of my variables are defined (`wsOutputData` is a Worksheet that works in the line immediately above it, and `lngOutputLastRow` is a Long variable that's currently evaluated to `25,841`).

Am I using the `Range.Formula` property incorrectly?

Edit: See selected answer below...spelling is hard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have formula spelled wrong..

change

```
wsOutputData.Range("E1").Fomula = "=SUBTOTAL(9,E3:E" & lngOutputLastRow & ")"
```

to

```
wsOutputData.Range("E1").Formula = "=SUBTOTAL(9,E3:E" & lngOutputLastRow & ")"
```

Sometimes you have one of those days :)

Comment: Holy. Crap.  IT'S NOT EVEN MONDAY!!! This one's going on the fridge.  Thanks for that :)

Comment: It happens to even the best..   After hours i once posted a question where i was setting something to itself and couldn't figure out what was wrong.